# How to rename a git folder to a previously existing folder name

Tags: git

I have a git repository on my computer.

Previously, I had a folder called `final_project` and I used to work on it. But after a while, I removed that whole folder and started a new folder `start_project` to work. Now I want to rename this <del>repository</del>folder to `final_project`, and I use:

```
git mv start_project final_project
```

but when I check the log, it shows me the history of first project which is not needed anymore and not applicable.

I think git needs another option to over-write the log of `start_project` to the log of `final_project` while moving. Is it possible? What is wrong with my command?

I use the following command to see the log of my projects:

```
git log folder_name
```

for example

```
~/Projects$ git log start_project
```

or

```
~/Projects/start_project/$ git log .
```

Comment: Are you saying you had two projects in the same git repository?

Comment: @MartinKonecny Yes, I treat my projects this way; I just add a folder to the repository and start working on them.

Comment: You should try to avoid this in the future. Then you wouldn't have this problem. git tracks all commits under the project root folder, so you will have some hassle deleting the old commit history - it can be done though.

Comment: To manage different versions of things in git, which is a, umm, VERSION CONTROL SYSTEM, use git branches which exist precisely for that purpose, not separate folders. Create a branch for each of your versions of the project. Otherwise, what's the point of using git at all?

Comment: **What command are you using to check the history? Can you please include what the output of the command is in your question?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this out. I created a folder named `foo`, then deleted it, created another folder named `skadoosh`, then renamed it to `foo`:

```
git log --oneline --graph --name-status
* 44fb01b Rename skadoosh to foo # <== Rename skadoosh to foo
| A     foo/derp.txt
| D     skadoosh/derp.txt
* c7af83c Add derp               # <== Create skadoosh
| A     skadoosh/derp.txt
* 344e215 Remove foo             # <== Delete foo
| D     foo/hello.txt
* cff7b45 Say goodbye
| M     foo/hello.txt
* 7fc9da5 Add hello.txt          # <== Create foo
  A     foo/hello.txt
```

This is the log of *just* the folder `foo`:

```
git log --oneline --graph --name-status -- foo
* 44fb01b Rename skadoosh to foo   # Add "foo" (was skadoosh)
| A     foo/derp.txt
* 344e215 Remove foo               # Delete foo
| D     foo/hello.txt
* cff7b45 Say goodbye
| M     foo/hello.txt
* 7fc9da5 Add hello.txt
  A     foo/hello.txt
```

**This makes sense.** `foo` was deleted in commit `344e215`, then "added" again (with different content) in commit `44fb01b`. Renaming a file or folder is handled by deleting the original file/folder, then adding it again with the new name.

### Git tracks file content, not directory paths

Why does the history of `git log -- foo` include the history of the original folder `foo/`? As many people have already pointed out, **Git doesn't track directories, it tracks file content**, so individual sub-folders wouldn't be treated as their own unique objects by Git, only the project root directory tree is treated as a unique object.

The command `git log -- foo` basically says to return the history for a directory tree path named `foo/`, and since Git doesn't treat the path `foo/` in any special way, **it just returns the history of all content that was ever placed in a path that was called** `foo/`.

I'm sure there's an even more detailed technical explanation that involves Git directory tree objects, but I'm not familiar enough with the low-level plumbing or source code to give a detailed explanation at this time.

#### Another Way to Look at It

Here's another way to look at it (it's probably more correct too). Since Git doesn't actually track sub-directories, *but only the content in those sub-directories*, it's more accurate to say that **you only delete and add files in sub-directories, you never actually add or delete sub-directories themselves.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a misconception here? With `git mv` you don't rename repositories, but just a folder or file of the repository. If you want to create a new repository you should to that with `git init final_project`. Git doesn't care about that name though, so you can rename it with `mv` at any time. If you want to actually give your repository a name you can do that in `.git/description`.

If you want to rename folders nothing is wrong with `git mv`. Git tracks content not files/directories, so you can even use the `mv` shell command and `git rm start_project` and `git add final_project`.

To get the log of an individual file across renames you have to use the `--follow` option like

```
git log --follow <filename>
```

If you just provide the directory name to `git log` there is no real "content" associated with it other than the directory name, so it only can show you the logs associated with that name. The `--follow` option works only on single files though, so if you want to have a clean history you should seriously reconsider you workflow of putting every project into one repository.

Comment: Sorry about it, but there was a typo in the text, I edited that. In fact, I wanted to rename the folder not a repository.

Comment: Note that technically it *is* possible to create a new project with a new history without initiating a new `git init` by issuing `rm .git/refs/heads/master` (assuming that's your current `HEAD`). Of course your old master will be eligible to garbage collection then if no references are left to it. I don't know why one should prefer that to just another `git init` though. Maybe it may make sense when you have a lot of local configurations which you don't want to copy over.

Comment: In fact I wasn't really familiar with `git`; I just saw an online tutorial that showed me this way and it was pretty straightforward.
I've got a few projects in that repository and I think I have to create a repository for each of them.